binascii.Error: Non-hexadecimal digit found - Error
такая же проблема, как и здесь.
я вписал секретную фразу в переменную, но пайтон выводит ошибку:

return binascii.unhexlify(ascii_hex)
binascii.Error: Non-hexadecimal digit found.

код:
seed_phrase = f". . ."

private_key = Account.from_key(seed_phrase)

user_address = private_key.address

print(f"Адрес пользователя на MetaMask: {user_address}")


Стек-трейс ошибки должен быть полный. Данные должны быть конкретные. Если фраза прям секретная-секретная, попробуйте из неё что-то поудалять, но так, чтобы ошибка сохранялась. И покажите то, что останется. Заодно может и сами поймёте, при каком условии ошибка возникает.

seed_phrase = f". . ." тут 12 слов на англисском.
